# VIM: how to select a line, up to the cursor, including the char under the cursor?

Tags: vim, gvim, vi

From normal mode I select what's before the cursor with:

```
v<Home>
```

Is adding to the selection what's under the cursor possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: At least over here, both `v<Home>` and `v^` select what's under the cursor as well. Do you want to select the character to the right of the cursor as well? If so, `lv^` may suffice!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

***edit***

You want to change the direction of the selection, right? Just type `o` and extend your selection as you need.

```
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        #                  " starting point
<########                  " v^
########>                  " o
##########>                " e
```

***endedit***

I'm not exactly sure about what you want so here are a bunch of selection combos.

Select from cursor to first column of the line:

```
v0
```

Select from cursor to first printable character of the line:

```
v^
```

Select from cursor to end of the line:

```
v$
```

Select from cursor to end of the word:

```
ve
```

Select from cursor to beginning of the word:

```
vb
```

Select from cursor to the next opening parenthesis on the line (inclusive):

```
vf(
```

Select from cursor to the previous double quote on the line (exclusive):

```
vT"
```

Select from cursor to the next occurence of `foo` in the buffer (always exclusive):

```
v/foo<CR>
```

Select from cursor to previous occurence of `bar` in the buffer (always exclusive):

```
v?bar<CR>
```

Select the whole word under cursor:

```
viw
```

Select everything between a pair of parenthesis:

```
vi( (or vib)
```

Select the body of a function:

```
vi{ (or viB)
```

Select a whole sentence:

```
vis
```

Select a whole paragraph:

```
vip
```

For even more, see `:help motion.txt`.